# Imagem inserida em html não quer aparecer

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD> 
<TITLE>Segundo HTML</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<P> Uma imagem </P>     
       <img src="C:/Users/Lucas/Pictures/Ogame.jpg" width="800" height="600">
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

O código acima não está exibindo a imagem, ao executar o html no navegador aparece apenas o contorno da imagem com aquele ícone de erro nela.

Não sei onde estou errando...

Comment: Caso tenha tentado as soluções acima e não resolva, tente mudar a extensão do arquivo para PNG. <img src="C:/Users/Lucas/Pictures/Ogame.png" width="800" height="600">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você está carregando esse *HTML* localmente, sem uso de um servidor, você pode só trocar o `src` da imagem para:

```
src="file://C:/Users/Lucas/Pictures/Ogame.jpg"
```

Porém, por questão de segurança, os navegadores não irão permitir isso no momento em que você publicar em um servidor.

Então recomendo você colocar a imagem no mesmo diretório do seu *HTML* ou em um subdiretório e referenciar ela de lá:

```
src="Ogame.jpg"
```

Answer (score 1):

O seu arquivo *.html* está na pasta *Lucas*?
Se ele está tente colocar assim:

```
<img src="Pictures/Ogame.jpg" width="800" height="600">
```

Caso não funcionar verifique se a imagem é mesmo *.jpg* ou se ela é de outra extensão como *.png* por exemplo